# Clearing back stack on transition

Tags: ios, back-stack

I have a storyboard set up using modal transitions as follows:

root -> A -> B -> C

When I transition from B to C, I want to clear the backstack because a user will never be able to get back to A, B or root.  I know it is not possible to remove the root view controller but is there a way to remove A and B from the stack when transition to C.

I have Android background and in there it can be done by simply adding CLEAR_TOP and NEW_TASK  flag to the intent before starting next activity. Is there something similar in iOS?

I am trying to call this on the on the transition from B->C but it crashes the app.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Also tried this on view did Load of B but it doesn't work.

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

EDIT: Is it possible to make C the root and clear A->B and previous root. How would you do that?

Comment: Maybe you can use `UINavigationController` to achieve what you want. After B->C, just clear the controller stack.

Comment: Main reason for using modal is because I want to use "flip horizontal" transition. I am not sure how to do this animation with push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is set yourself as the window's root view controller in the viewDidAppear method of C.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.view.window.rootViewController = self;
}
```

Root, A, and B will be deallocated when you do this.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the deallocation part.  I thought that I would be creating a memory leak by just changing root (i.e. the previous views will still be floating around).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use UINavigationController to achieve what you want. After B->C, just clear the controller stack.
You can custom the transition style of `UINavigationController` like this:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.3];
[animation setType: kCATransitionMoveIn];
[animation setSubtype: kCATransitionFromTop];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction   functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];

[nav pushViewController:yourViewController animated:NO];

[nav.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Comment: I have never used storyboard. I think you should link the `Next` button to an action method in which you 1) alloc & initialize your second view controller and 2) use the code snippet to push it to UINavigationController.

Comment: Note that you can replace root, A, and B with C by using the `setViewControllers:animated:` method instead of `pushViewController:animated:` and animate it this way.

Comment: > *just clear the controller stack* < - where is this happening in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `-removeFromSuperview`

Comment: Are you referring to [self removeFromParentViewController]  I have tried this, it doesn't work.  The previous view, in this case B is still there.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can use is:

root-> A -> B -> C -> (fakeRoot) => (real root)

Before leaving root, you can create a snapshot of the root ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710695/793607))

Then you can use your fancy modal transition to transition to the "fake root" but put the real root behind it, in the type of controller you want for moving forward.  Then just remove the fake root to expose the real one.

- Make a viewController called "fakeRoot" controller that was just a big imageView that fills the screen
- Set the imageView to the image of "root" that you created with the snapshot above.
- do your modal transition to this imageView
- pop to the root of your nav controller without animation (that should make root appear, but you won't notice because your modally presented view will looks just like it)

Comment: I am having a hard time wrapping my head around what you said.  Can you maybe elaborate.  Also please see edit.  I would still prefer doing it by using modal transition but I can do push if that is the best way of dealing with back stack.